# Output a large nested array with both sub-arrays and number objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I am keeping track of each round of hands/results dealt in a blackjack game. I need to output each "round" as a single line. There are 'x' number of rounds. I am storing the results for each round in a big array. My problem is I have 2 arrays within my big array and 2 numeric. I need to output each of the 4 'objects' per line, as round results. I cannot figure out how to 'parse' the non-numeric array objects  mixed with the numeric objects. Should I just create two arrays, one object and one numeric and output them separately? 
Output goal is 1st line: 
3,2,9,6;10,2,6;3,10
and so on for each round, one line.

```
    <script>
    var ph = [3,2,9,6]; var dh = [10,2,6]; var seq = 3, var bet = 10; var result; 
    allhands.push(ph);allhands.push(dh);allhands.push(seq);allhands.push(bet)
    //allhands looks like this:[[3,2,9,6], [10,2,6], 3,10]
    function showallhands(){    
    for (e = 0;e<allhands.length;e++){
    for (f = 0; allhands[e][f];f ++){
    result += allhands[e] + allhands[e][f]+";"+"<br >" ;
    }          
    }
    return result;
    }
    </script>

result = showallhands();
document.getElementById("ALLhands").innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: "`${ph.join(',')}; ${dh.join(',')}; ${seq}, ${bet}`;"

Comment: @random  That might work for the first line, but how do I parse/output an array of 100 rounds with 4 elements for each round? How do I address the 5th "element" and so on? Using [0] and so on doesn't identify the ph, dh arrays inside the bigger array, they are not numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to create a game object then store the hands in it:

```js
        function Game() {
            this.ph = [3, 2, 9, 6];
            this.dh = [10, 2, 6];
            this.seq = 3;
            this.bet = 10;
            this.getHands = function () {
                return this.ph + ';' + this.dh + ';' + this.seq + ';' + this.bet + ';<br>';
            };
        };

        var games = [];
        games.push(new Game());
        games.push(new Game());
        games.push(new Game());

        var result = "";

        function showallhands() {
            for (e = 0; e < games.length; e++) {
                result += games[e].getHands();
            }
            return result;
        }

        result = showallhands();
        document.getElementById("ALLhands").innerHTML = result;
```

If you want to keep the array and not use OOP, I think this would do the trick:

```js
 var arr = [
            [3, 2, 9, 6],
            [10, 2, 6], 3, 10, "hello"
        ];

        arr.forEach(function each(item) {
            if (Array.isArray(item)) {
                item.forEach(each);
            } else {
                console.log(item);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have not used 'this' before. Looking at your code, how do I input each new round of ph,dh,seq,and bet? I used the static values above as an example. Do I .push each value into Game during the function? If I just call  games.push(new Game()); when round is complete, will the new values of ph,dh,seq,and bet populate via "this". Thank you again for your time.

Comment: you can create a new Game when the game starts and access the variables like this: ```var game1 = new game();
        game1.seq = 1;
        game.bet = 10;
        game1.ph.push(10);
        game1.dh.push(7);
```    I also updated the answer to just use the array in case you dont want to use OOP